# Windows Services и запуск функции по таймеру

Tags: c#, windows-service

Пытаюсь написать службу которая каждую минуту будет записывать в файл фразу, предположим "Hello World" с новой строки.

На просторах этого сайта нашел отличный код, который позволяет это делать по таймеру:

```
    var startTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero;
    var periodTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0.1);

    var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
    {
        every_time();
    }, null, startTimeSpan, periodTimeSpan);
```

Добавил в своей функции запись в файл. Собрал проект, добавил в службы, запустил.

Первый раз функция отработала, а вот дальше - не хочет. В службах отмечено, что служба выполняется, но в файл ничего не записывает. Дата последнего изменения тоже не изменяется.

Попробовал вызвать этот таймер в консольном приложении, добавив в конце Console.ReadKey(); - все работает, каждую секунду добавляет "Hello World".

Почему не хочет так же выполнятся в службе, я не могу понять. 
Возможно что-то делаю не так.

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в таймере, он не из того пространства имен, используйте System.Timers.Timer

Comment: Или в том, что timer - локальная переменная, которую подбирает сборщик мусора раньше времени. Надо в поле класса ее пихать.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight я её пихаю в функцию OnStart(string[] args), которая отвечает за запуск службы

Comment: @NickProskuryakov попробовал как вы советовали. Тоже самое, 1 раз выполняется и все

Comment: Таймер должен быть полем класса, а не локальной переменной.

Comment: @tym32167 сделал как вы говорите. Результат такой же - отрабатывает 1 раз

Comment: Добавьте ваш код в вопрос

Comment: Уточнение - не любым полем класса, а именно существующем все время работы программы (в простейшем случае, статическое поле)